# Making two <div>s inside a wrapper that goes 100 %

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work out a problem where I have a centered div (margin: 0 auto) with a fixed width that has some content in it, followed by a new div, that is supposed to have to divs next to each other, with a wrapping total width of 100 %.

The left div needs to follow the left "margin" of the fixed width wrapper, while the right div is just going to be a map.

I've included an illustration to explain things more visually. I've come to a state where I could have margin-left on the left div and with JS calculate the (width of the screen - fixed width div) / 2, but I want to see if this would be possible with just HTML and CSS and I can't come up with a method. Any ideas?

[image: mockup]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a general concept of thinking and even if I would like to provide some code, I find it almost unnecessary, since I probably start from the wrong place. But I'm about to answer Apolo in a more in-depth way.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this, from your question I think it appears to satisfy your needs.

```css
.centre-align {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 60%;
   background-color: #808080;
   min-height: 300px;
  }

  .left-outline {
   width: 40%;
   margin:0 0 0 -20%;
   border:none;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   padding:0;
   display: inline-block;
   min-height: 100px;
   background-color:#4cff00;
  }

  .right-outline {
   width: 100%;
   margin:0 -40% 0 0;
   border:none;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   padding:0;
   display: inline-block;
   min-height: 100px;
   background-color:#f00;
  }
```

```html
 <div>
  <div class="centre-align">
   <div>Bacon ipsum dolor amet shank pig porchetta bacon shoulder. Fatback capicola andouille boudin, venison meatloaf doner ground round. Landjaeger chicken boudin, meatball capicola shank kevin tenderloin. Sirloin pig meatloaf, venison brisket shoulder drumstick tongue kielbasa ball tip. Leberkas porchetta jerky doner, shank salami pancetta pig tenderloin strip steak ham fatback beef picanha ham hock.</div>
   <div class="left-outline">
    TEXT
   </div>
   <div class="right-outline">
    MAP
   </div>
<div>Bacon ipsum dolor amet shank pig porchetta bacon shoulder. Fatback capicola andouille boudin, venison meatloaf doner ground round. Landjaeger chicken boudin, meatball capicola shank kevin tenderloin. Sirloin pig meatloaf, venison brisket shoulder drumstick tongue kielbasa ball tip. Leberkas porchetta jerky doner, shank salami pancetta pig tenderloin strip steak ham fatback beef picanha ham hock.</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That is actually not a shabby a proposition! The only two things I'm missing is the green box's text to be aligned with the gray area and the two colored boxes to be dynamic, i.e. fill the rest of the screen with the width, no matter the screen size.

Comment: Those Div's will expand to the size of the screen as they have % widths, you just need to play with them to get the desired width and margin of each box. The Green Div can contain any layout you wish using the same method to align with the grey box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood everything in your question but it seems pretty easy :

```css
#page {
    width:500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;/* half of wrapper height */
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#left {
    background: blue;
}

#right {
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left" class="child">TEXT</div>
        <div id="right" class="child">MAP</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Let me know if it does not answer your question, I will edit.**

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the concept is a little bit more complicated than that. The gray area in my illustration is the wrapper. All kinds of content, except for the map, needs to stay in that area - including the blue areas right part, that contains "TEXT". The thing is, that blue div also has to be able to continue to the left, to infinity, while the part that's inside the fixed width wrapper can be of a fixed width.
The map on the other hand needs to be the rest of the width of the window and stretch as long as possible.

Does that explain things better?